# How to get clients actual address in java

Tags: microservices, clientip

We have an application which runs on multiple microservice systems.Lets consider a scenario where client requests something from microservice1 and microservice1 invokes an API on microservice2. In this scenario I want to get clients_ip_address in microservice2. Is there a provision where I can get client_ip_address from request_header ?
Thanks
Srumith.

Comment: I think you must *somehow* forward the original client's IP address, i.e. by inserting a header, like proxies do with `X_FORWARDED_FOR`. The actual way depends a lot to the frameworks/libraries you use.

Answer (score 1):

User `getRemoteAddr()` method of request.

```
ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```